# Java modules - module not found: org.slf4j

Tags: java, java-module

I am studying **java modules** and faced with this error:

I tried to put this "module in my declaration"

```
module mymodule {
  requires org.slf4j;
}
```

--
`mvn clean package`

`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile module not found: org.slf4j`

My pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I found that the "Automatic module name is":

```
module mymodule {
  requires org.apache.logging.log4j.slf4j;
}
```

But now I have this error:

```
(package org.slf4j is declared in the unnamed module, but module org.slf4j does not read it)
```

How can I solve this? Whys this is happening?